# iOS: Interface not refreshing

Tags: ios, user-interface, refresh

In my app, I create an EKCalendar. Since the calendar could be deleted by the user outside my app, I need to check if that calendar still exists, like so:

```
-(BOOL)checkForCalendar {

    NSArray *calendarArray = [self.store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];


    NSUserDefaults *defaults    = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *calNameToCheckFor = [defaults objectForKey:@"calendarName"];

    EKCalendar *cal;

    for (int x = 0; x < [calendarArray count]; x++) {

        cal = [calendarArray objectAtIndex:x];
        NSString *calTitle = [cal title];

        // if the calendar is found, return YES
        if ([calTitle isEqualToString:calNameToCheckFor]) {

            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;

}
```

I want my UI to update, if a calendar indeed is deleted, as such:

```
-(void)initCalendarState {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![self checkForCalendar]){
        [self.LoginSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
        [userDefaults setObject:@"0" forKey:@"SwitchedOn"];
    }
}
```

I have put this method in the Application's Delegate

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Things I observe:

1) If I go through this code step by step in the debugger, it is called on the correct moment, and is executed as expected: running in the main thread, honoring all conditions etc.

2) However: when it gets to updating the UI, ([self.LoginSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];), nothing happens.

3) When I rerun the project (effectively force quitting it, and restarting) the UI actually IS updated.

What am I missing?

The concrete question is: why isn't my UI updated while the app is running?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening, is that the changes I made in my local calendar were not fully proliferated through the iCloud sync system. Or something like it. Not sure.
However: to solve my problem, I added

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(storeChanged:)
                                                 name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification
                                               object:self.store];
```

to my app.

and

```
-(void)storeChanged:(NSNotification *) notification {

    [self initCalendarState];
}
```

This works flawlessly.